# Usage of ZODB temporary storage

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

In [plone.recipe.zope2instance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance) there is an option called `zodb-temporary-storage` that is used to replace Zope's default temporary storage definition.

When is this recommended? What are the upsides and downsides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the recipe includes a [*temporary storage service*](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/ZopeServices.html#temporary-storage-services) to store session data:

> Temporary Folders are Zope folders that are used for storing objects temporarily. Temporary Folders acts almost exactly like a regular Folder with two significant differences:
>
> - Everything contained in a Temporary Folder disappears when you restart Zope. (A Temporary Folder’s contents are stored in RAM).
> - You cannot undo actions taken to objects stored a Temporary Folder.

This is great for the highly volatile session data, but if you are running Zope in a cluster you may want to swap out the storage for something that shared data across your cluster, for example.

The default configuration used is:

```xml
<zodb_db temporary>
    # Temporary storage database (for sessions)
    <temporarystorage>
      name temporary storage for sessioning
    </temporarystorage>
    mount-point /temp_folder
    container-class Products.TemporaryFolder.TemporaryContainer
</zodb_db>
```

which corresponds with the default [session management setup for Zope](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Sessions.html).

I've always avoided using Zope's sessions, as they can easily become a bottleneck (loads of conflicts on the temporary storage), opting to store everything in cookies instead. If you really need server-side session storage, using [Beaker](https://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (via [`collective.beaker`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.beaker/) might be a better option.

Better still, use [`Products.BeakerSessionDataManager`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.BeakerSessionDataManager) to swap out the default Zope session manager to one backed by Beaker.

Comment: @hvelarde: unless you have a specific need to swap that out.

Comment: You might want to mention https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.BeakerSessionDataManager which provides a drop-in replacement for standard Zope sessions using collective.beaker.

Comment: @DavidGlick: see, I knew there was one more package to mention, thanks! (and congrats on your wedding! :-))